# Python/Pandas: Loop to append Excel files ONLY if each Excel file contains certain values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, openpyxl, pyexcel

I have the following code:

```
dfs = []
    for f in files_xlsx:
            city_name = pd.read_excel(f, "1. City", nrows=1, parse_cols="C", header=None, skiprows=1)
            country_code = pd.read_excel(f, "1. City", nrows=1, parse_cols="C", header=None, skiprows=2)
            data = pd.read_excel(f, "1. City", parse_cols="B:J", header=None, skiprows=8)
            data['City name'] = city_name.iat[0,0]
            data['City code'] = country_code.iat[0,0]
            dfs.append(data)

    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

I would like to run the loop if and only if each Excel file contains the values `91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97` in the following location (column and row combination) `D8, E8, F8, G8, H8, I8, J8`. The loop should only run if this condition is met across all files.

All my Excel files have the same format in theory. In practice, they often don't so I want to run a check before appending them. It would be great if the code could tell me which file does *not* meet the above condition. Thank you.

**Edit**:

```
In[1]: data

Out[1]:

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   City name   City code
0   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x           x
1   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x           x
2   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x           x
```

Comment: Why not check that row directly in the files using xlrd?

Comment: @CharlieClark, thx for the suggestion. how would I incorporate that into the loop though?

Comment: You could start by opening the relevant file in read-only mode and continuing if the check fails. I don't think you really need to use Pandas here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a helper data frame that resembles Excel data but with values matched to specification (row 8 and columns D-J with those specific values). Then in loop iteratively merge against this helper data frame and if it returns a match, conditionally append to your list of data frames.

**NOTE:** Adjust columns to actual column names, replacing `list('ABCDEFGHIJ')` with list of names, `['col1','col2','col3',...]`, in `DataFrame()` and `merge()` calls.

```
check_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[0]*9 for _ in range(7)], 
                                    columns=['Heading code','Heading name','91','92','93','94','95','96','97']),
                      pd.DataFrame([[0,0,91,92,93,94,95,96,97]], 
                                   columns=['Heading code','Heading name','91','92','93','94','95','96','97'])],
                      ignore_index=True).reset_index()

print(check_df)    
#    index  Heading code  Heading name  91  92  93  94  95  96  97
# 0      0             0             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 1      1             0             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2      2             0             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 3      3             0             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 4      4             0             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 5      5             0             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 6      6             0             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 7      7             0             0  91  92  93  94  95  96  97

dfs = []
for f in files_xlsx:
   city_name = pd.read_excel(f, "1. City", nrows=1, parse_cols="C", header=None, skiprows=1)
   country_code = pd.read_excel(f, "1. City", nrows=1, parse_cols="C", header=None, skiprows=2)
   data = pd.read_excel(f, "1. City", parse_cols="B:J", header=None, skiprows=8)\
            .assign(city_name=city_name.iat[0,0], city_code=country_code.iat[0,0])
   data.columns = ['Heading code','Heading name','91','92','93','94','95','96','97','City name','City code']

   # INNER JOIN MERGE ON INDEX AND COLS, D-J
   tmp = data.reset_index().merge(check_df, on=['index','91','92','93','94','95','96','97'])    

   # CONDITIONALLY APPEND
   if len(tmp) > 0:
        dfs.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Below demonstrates with random data

```
np.random.seed(82118)
# LIST OF FIVE DATAFRAMES (TO RESEMBLE EXCEL DFs)
rand_dfs = [pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(1, 100, 9) for _ in range(10)],
                    columns=['Heading code','Heading name','91','92','93','94','95','96','97'])
            for _ in range(5)]

# UPDATE TWO DATAFRAMES EACH WITH 10 COLS TO INCLUDE MATCHING 8TH ROW
rand_dfs[2].loc[7] = [0, 0, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97]    
rand_dfs[4].loc[7] = [0, 0, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97]

final_dfs = []
for d in rand_dfs:
    tmp = d.reset_index().merge(check_df, on=['index','91','92','93','94','95','96','97'])

    if len(tmp) > 0: 
        final_dfs.append(d)

final_df = pd.concat(final_dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Output (*see 8th and 17th rows with matching criteria)*

```
print(final_df)

#     Heading code  Heading name  91  92  93  94  95  96  97
# 0             53            98  67   8  86  33  65  56  62
# 1             61             9  40  14  18   9  53  30  24
# 2             89            88  80  91  91  49   8  39  84
# 3             15            99  49  92  63  96  11  95  29
# 4             13            62  82  12  34  92  54  29  47
# 5             44            18  67  61  52  71  52  25  12
# 6             56            25  52  10  82  12  59  63  15
# 7              0             0  91  92  93  94  95  96  97
# 8             51            50  27  38  34  11  57  92   3
# 9             49            99  46  87  46   5  63  24   8
# 10            31            62   8  23  19  66  60  10  66
# 11            51            98  30  44  45  39  32  74  82
# 12            88            19  54  28  38  71   3  31  34
# 13            58            13  89  17  96  35  12  52  85
# 14            93            67  13  13  28  43  24   7   4
# 15            34            26  73  20  44  37  18  17  22
# 16            59             1  99   9  11   6   4  99  95
# 17             0             0  91  92  93  94  95  96  97
# 18            88             6  23  20  35  26  37  56  51
# 19            21            67  19  63  77  98  41   9  22
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling with getting the inner join merge line to work. My `data` DataFrame has no column names/headers except for city name and city code, see my edit above. In my original code I would actually add the column headers _after_ I had appended the files. In this case, the list of column headers would be: `['Heading code','Heading name',91,92,93,94,95,96,97,'City name','City code']`. Given this information, what should list information should I then put in the DataFrame and merge calls?

Comment: See updated code using your column headers all in string types for `merge`.

Comment: Thanks again. However, now I get an error. `NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-0f2a938d806b> in <module>()
      6 
      7    # INNER JOIN MERGE ON INDEX AND COLS, D-J
----> 8    tmp = d.reset_index().merge(check_df, on=['index','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017'])
      9 
     10    # CONDITIONALLY APPEND

NameError: name 'd' is not defined` I tried running it on Python 3 and 3.6

Comment: I added `d =[]` at the beginning of the code and that created a different error : `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'`

Comment: Hi @Parfait, any chance you can take a look at this again? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whoops, typo! The `d` should have been `data`. See edit.

Comment: Thanks again. However, yet again, another issue came up. I tried modifying the code with no success. Again, your help would be appreciated. See my edit above.

Comment: See update. You have to also name the columns of *data* in loop (adjust as needed) in order to `merge` with *check_df*. Btw - you should update your question post for any new items not in a poster's current answer.

Comment: Thanks again. After your latest edit, I get the error `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`. Interestingly enough, not listing the column `index` in `tmp = data.reset_index().merge(check_df, on=['index','91','92','93','94','95','96','97'])` allows the code to run, but the result is that no files are concatenated.

Comment: Sounds like `merge` returned nothing in each iteration. Check carefully if the 8th row (i.e., index #7 since pandas is zero-index) really does have your exact values 91 in '2011' column, 92 in '2012' column, etc. I added my test case to show solution works.